# Is there a daily quota for Google Forms created in Google App Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, limit, google-forms, quota

I intend to write a script which will create many Google Forms and I want to find out if i will be able to run it with a consumer account.

The documentation (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) specifies a daily quota of "documents created". Do Forms count towards this quota or does it refer only to Google Docs? Can I create unlimited forms otherwise?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) specifies quotas for `Documents created`, `Presentations created` and `Spreadsheets created`.

If there is any quota for maximum created forms - there is no public information about this.

Even if there is no quota considering the maximum amount of forms created, you should still be careful to not run into other quota issues like e.g. maximum script execution time.